# Is there an algorithm to classify a TTF font into a generic font-family programmatically?

Tags: css, fonts, pdf-generation, truetype

I've been trying to develop a font maintenance application for our environment, and one of the aspects I need to group our fonts into is the generic font family (as per *CSS*). Thus: `monospace`, `serif`, `sans-serif`, `fantasy`, and `cursive`. I've been parsing the *TTF* fonts and have concluded the best place to try and determine these qualities to be the TTF *os/2* **PANOSE** sub-field(s).

The `monospace`, `serif` and `sans-serif` was easy, `cursive` script was not too difficult, but I found that `fantasy` display fonts were a bit ambiguous.

For instance, I found that Helvetica could fall in either `sans-serif` or `fantasy` (and some resources I've encountered classified it as both), however I prioritized it as `sans-serif` in our environment (In our environment I have to pick one, and the user can override).

But what I would prefer is a definitive guide to this type of classification.

I think I'm mostly on the right track, I would just like more formal resources and guides, but I cannot find any.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but doesn’t the browser go the other way, with preset fonts for each CSS generic family? (Well, sets of fonts, for families and languages and platforms.) Not sure it ever ends up classifying arbitrary fonts into those generic families.

Comment: That was just an example, but they had made that choice in some way, perhaps programmatically, or perhaps visually. That is also unknown to me. I, however, as per my question, need an algorithmic way to get the same result programmatically.

Comment: I've done my research, I've read through: https://www.w3.org/Fonts/Panose/pan2.html
And the entire TTF font spec. I also know most of the PDF spec.
None of these actually give definitive answers on `fantasy` (or display font typeface) generic families.

Comment: Pretty sure they made it visually. So the problem as it pertains to CSS doesn’t really make sense.

Comment: I've removed that sentence as it was detracting from my question.

Comment: You still have “as per CSS” and that doesn’t make sense because you don’t actually have to pick a font matching the qualities of the generic family to represent that generic family.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156563/discussion-between-marius-and-ryan).

Comment: So… it sounds like font classification should be done by someone entering the font into your system. Unless you want to do some kind of funky AI that’ll predict how people feel about whether a given font fits into a given CSS generic family.

Comment: A few rules would still have to apply. For instance, can a font be both `display` (fantasy) and `sans-serif` perhaps... but never both `serif` and `sans-serif` these are perhaps *obvious*. But are there formal definitions someplace?

Comment: A well-contrived font can fit all the categories at once. (example: half of the characters have serifs, monospace, looks handwritten, too fancy for body)

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I have to this, which is not an algorithm, but which I based my personal one on, is the following table depicting PANOSE font visual classification attributes:

https://forum.high-logic.com/postedfiles/Panose.pdf

These I get from the `panose` field inside the TTF's `os/2` table.